# SSH client on Linux Mint 20 doesn't prompt for user presence confirmation via FIDO USB device

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, openssh, yubikey

I recently received a [Security Key by Yubico](https://www.yubico.com/products/security-key/) (supports FIDO/U2F) and I am testing SSH authentication using this key.

Quoting the OpenSSH 8.2 release notes (Changes since OpenSSH 8.1 section):

> In OpenSSH FIDO devices are supported by new public key types
> "ecdsa-sk" and "ed25519-sk" [...]

After creating an `ecdsa-sk` key using `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk` without providing a passphrase for this (test) key, I appended the contents of `id_ecdsa_sk.pub` to the `${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on a remote host as usual.

When I try to create an SSH connection to the remote host, nothing is displayed but the security key device flashes, prompting for touch input. As soon as I touch the device, the SSH connection establishes.

After some web searches ([Sample result](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/5b9720f9adbd70ba5a994f407fe07a7d016d8d65/ssh-agent.c#L405)) I believe that I should have been prompted with a message like this:

```
Confirm user presence for key ECDSA-SK SHA256:blah-blah-blah
```

How can I fix this problem?

Note that the same behavior is observed for `ed25519-sk`.

#### Environment info

- Local and Remote OS: `Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon`
- Local and Remote OpenSSH: `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

Comment: It looks like the "confirm user presence" message can be printed out by `ssh-agent` or by `ssh`.  But `ssh-agent` isn't likely to have its stderr attached to your terminal.  If you're using `ssh-agent`, can you try running your `ssh` command without an agent:  `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh remotehost`.

Comment: @satwell I guess you are correct. I set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=''`, then ran the ssh command and I was prompted to confirm user presence. Nevertheless, I would expect to be prompted just like it happens for passwords.

Answer (score 3):

The SSH agent is interacting with your security key, not `ssh` itself.  In most configurations, the agent is not attached to your terminal.  Which means that it can't print the message to your terminal.  In Mint Cinnamon, GNOME Keyring is used as the SSH agent by default, but this also applies to `ssh-agent`.

You've got a couple options for getting this prompt.

#### Use ssh-askpass

If you're in X, then your agent can use the `ssh-askpass` to prompt you via a pop-up window.  Most frequently used for prompting for passwords (hence the name), but it also works for presence confirmation prompts with both GNOME Keyring and `ssh-agent`.  On a Debian-based distro like Mint, this should be as simple as `apt install ssh-askpass-gnome`.  (There are other variants as well, such as the more-plain `ssh-askpass`.)

#### Remove the key from the agent

If you'd prefer to get the prompt in your terminal, then you can get `ssh` to prompt you by simply keeping `id_ecdsa_sk` out of the agent.  `ssh` will first attempt to authenticate with the agent and then fall back to default key names in `~/.ssh`.

With GNOME Keyring, all keys in `~/.ssh` automatically get added to the agent.  So to remove them, you need to move the keys out of the directory.  E.g.,

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/noauto
mv ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk* ~/.ssh/noauto/
```

Then add an `IdentityFile` option in `~/.ssh/config` for hosts where you want to use this key:

```
Host remotename
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/noauto/id_ecdsa_sk
```

If you happen to be using `ssh-agent` instead of GNOME Keyring, then instead of moving the keys to a different directory, you can delete the key from your agent with `ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk`.

Alternatively, if you're using `ssh-agent` and have an easy way to pass options to `ssh-agent`, you could set `-P` to the empty string.  I.e., run `ssh-agent -P ""`.  This would effectively blacklist loading all PKCS#11 and FIDO based keys into your agent.

Note that removing `id_ecdsa_sk` from `ssh-agent` may affect the ordering of the keys tried.  If you have a security key based ssh key and a traditional ssh key configured on both client and server sides, this could mean you end up authenticating with the traditional key instead of the security key.  Removing the key from the agent also means that you can't use the key on remote hosts with agent forwarding (`ssh -A`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I tried removing the `id_ecdsa` key from the ssh-agent but I get the following error: `Could not remove identity [...]: agent refused operation`. I don't manually add the keys to the agent. I just place them in `$HOME/.ssh` directory. Don't you think that the user presence prompt should work without any user modifications?

Comment: What program are you using as an ssh agent?  The values of `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `ps -o comm= -q $SSH_AGENT_PID` can be useful for figuring this out if you don't know.  Can you add this info to your question?  Ideally, yeah, it would all Just Work™.  But it's a little complicated with multiple agent implementations, and the security key support is pretty new.

Comment: Unfortunately no useful information can be derived from  `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` or `ps`. I can see that package `openssh-client` (Version: `8.2p1` as mentioned in the original question)  prοvides the `ssh-agent` program.

Comment: @gzach I got a chance to play with this some more, and it looks like Mint Cinnamon uses GNOME Keyring as the default ssh agent.  Installing an askpass binary (e.g., `sudo apt install ssh-askpass-gnome`) works for me--I get a pop-up window with a "Confirm user presence for key ..." message.  Does this work for you?

Comment: I do confirm that `ssh-askpass-gnome` prompts for user presence. (Strange thing, when the security key is not inserted I am prompted for the password in the command line.) Nevertheless, I would prefer the prompt to be displayed in the terminal. I am planning to use the security key on servers with no GUI.